# Prevent doctest incorrect failure when unordered output is involved

Tags: python, python-3.4, doctest, unordered

Suppose we have the function below:

```
def f(x):
    """
    Turns x into a set.

    >>> given_x = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f']
    >>> f(given_x)
    {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f'}

    """

    return set(x)
```

Running the doctest will (usually) cause something like this:

```
Failure
**********************************************************************
File "/home/black/Dev/exp_2.py", line 6, in f
Failed example:
    f(given_x)
Expected:
    {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f'}
Got:
    {'d', 'e', 'f', 'c', 'a', 'b'}
```

Apparently this failure shouldn't have happened since the function works as expected, but it did because of the result being unordered.

---

My actual function's output can be much more complex than this. It could be a dict with dicts, sets, lists inside of it.

I need a general solution (if there is one). Simply `sort()` on the presented example would not solve my real case problem.

**Question:**
How can I prevent the doctest from (incorrectly) failing when unordered output is involved?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why not just move the expected output up so you're testing for equality, with an expected output of "True"?

```
def f(x):
    """
    Turns x into a set. 

    >>> given_x = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f']
    >>> f(given_x) == {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f'}
    True
    """

    return set(x)
```

Output:

```
Trying:
    given_x = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f']
Expecting nothing
ok
Trying:
    f(given_x) == {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f'}
Expecting:
    True
ok
```

Comment: This solution works for objects but not for testing functions that return strings.  Real world case: generating html output. Html doesn't care about attribute order so it's logical to represent tag attrs in a dict() for later rendering.  When trying to doctest the render() function the attribute order in the string is not predictable.

Answer (score 0):

Order is not guaranteed fr python sets, so you can't rely on it.

I'd force to have something you could trust:

```
>>> given_x = ['z','a', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f']
>>> type(f(given_x))
<type 'dict'>
>>> sorted(list(f(given(x))) 
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f','z']
```

I test that it has expected type, that it actually did the "uniqueness" of the set and the result is what I expect

Comment: I apologize, I should have mentioned my `f()` output is much more complex. See updated question for more details. I am looking for a general solution (if there is one), not a solution specific to the example in the question.